# From Process Explorer, Is it possible to get the exact number of total bytes used for working memory and private memory?

Tags: memory, process-explorer

From Process Explorer, Is it possible to get the exact number of total bytes used for working memory and private memory?

[image]

Those numbers look like they are to the nearest thousand bytes. (or they are to the nearest multiple of 1024 bytes)

But can process explorer show it to the byte?  e.g. for Chrome

I know powershell can but wondering if process explorer can?

Comment: Why do you expect the size to be in bytes? Windows uses a page size of 4096 bytes.

Comment: "Process, Working Set, _Total: This counter is a measure of the virtual memory in "active" use.

This counter shows how much RAM is required so that the virtual memory being used for all processes is in RAM. This value is always a multiple of 4,096, which is the page size that is used in Windows. "

Comment: [RAM, virtual memory, pagefile, and memory management in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2160852/ram-virtual-memory-pagefile-and-memory-management-in-windows)

Comment: @DavidPostill ok so that explains that aspect.. eg not going within the page

Comment: Presumably.....

Comment: @DavidPostill ok thanks, you can post that as an answer and  I will accept it

Comment: Answer added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Does Process Explorer display the exact number of total bytes for working/private memory?

No. Windows uses a page size of 4096 bytes, so the numbers are always a multiple of 4096:

> Process, Working Set, _Total: This counter is a measure of the virtual memory in "active" use.
>
> This counter shows how much RAM is required so that the virtual memory being used for all processes is in RAM. This value is always a multiple of 4,096, which is the page size that is used in Windows.

Source [RAM, virtual memory, pagefile, and memory management in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2160852/ram-virtual-memory-pagefile-and-memory-management-in-windows)

Note that the above quote is referring to Performance Monitor, but I expect that it also true for Process Explorer (which may even use Performance Counters under the hood).

As an example here is the detailed memory usage for the System process on Windows 7 (from Process Hacker - Properties). The smallest block size is 4kb.

> [image]

Comment: Given that Process Explorer says that private memory used by chrome is 1106724, would you say that for Private Memory,  the total (to the nearest 4096 bytes), would be 1106724 * 1024? so 1133285376 bytes?

Comment: I guess so. Does something make you think otherwise?

Comment: well, this puzzles me https://superuser.com/questions/1544208/why-does-there-seem-to-be-a-discrepancy-by-a-factor-of-10-for-private-and-work