# Why's there a discrepancy by a factor of 10, for memory figures, with process explorer, compared to e.g. powershell and process hacker?

Tags: memory, powershell, process-explorer

Why does there seem to be a discrepancy by a factor of 10, for the private memory figure and working set memory figure, in the data given by process explorer, compared to that of powershell and process hacker. It looks like process explorer is the odd one out.

[image]

So process explorer says

```
PM- 1106724K
WS- 1187288K
```

If I multiply them by 1024 to get bytes,

```
PM- 1133285376 <-- 10 digits long (1.1 Gig)
WS- 1215782912 <-- 10 digits long (1.2 Gig)
```

Whereas Powershell says

Note- WS=WorkingSet    PM=PrivateMemory

```
PS C:\Users\harvey> (Get-Process chrome | Measure-Object WS -sum).sum
17073758208  <-- 11 digits long  (~17GB-decimal-base, or 15.8GB-binary-base)
PS C:\Users\harvey> (Get-Process chrome | Measure-Object PM -sum).sum
14065111040  <-- 11 digits long  (~14GB-decimal-base, or 13GB-binary-base )
```

So it looks like there's a factor of 10 difference between process explorer, and others e.g. powershell.  A difference between single digit GB, and double digit GB.

For private memory, 1133285376 vs 17073758208

For working memory, 1215782912 vs 14065111040

Besides that one might ask why the numbers aren't exactly the same.

Why are they out by a factor of 10?

Process Hacker agrees with the general magnitude given by Powershell, of 10s of GB.

Note- Added working set memory by right clicking column headers and choose column.
[image]

Comment: Hmm. System from Process Hacker reports 196k private bytes = 200704 bytes.
(Get-Process System | Measure-Object PM -sum).sum reports 200704

Comment: @DavidPostill hmm https://i.imgur.com/ReLks10.png  can process hacker show working set memory?

Comment: Yes. Right click column headers and choose columns.

Comment: Hmm. Numbers are different between Process Explorer and Process Hacker. I wonder why (they are the same for the System process though)

Comment: @DavidPostill  process hacker agrees with process explorer in terms of general magnitude, of double digit giga..  So process explorer is out by a factor of 10. (there may be some small discrepancy besides that but that's another matter!)

Comment: @DavidPostill just updated q with process hacker info

Comment: Ahaha. Process Explorer **does not add up the memory** when you click the minus sign. It still shows the memory for the single process showing. Process Hacker **does** add up the memory.

Comment: @DavidPostill ah thanks, that makes sense, and I  notice here https://superuser.com/questions/736324/can-task-manager-show-the-total-memory-usage-for-a-group-of-processes   nobody mentions process explorer for getting total memory used by all processes of the same filename.  or for total used by chrome, but they do mention process hacker.  You can post what you said as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why are they out by a factor of 10?

- Process Explorer **does not add up the memory** when you click the minus sign. It still shows the memory for the single process showing.
- Process Hacker **does** add up the memory (if it is configured to do so).

So in your case the smaller number from Process Hacker is for a single Chrome process and the larger number from Process Hacker is a total for all the Chrome processes.

Note that this is a configurable option in Process Hacker (Options->Advanced->Include CPU (and other) usage of children in collapsed processes) as detailed in [windows - Can Task Manager show the total memory usage for a group of processes? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/736324/can-task-manager-show-the-total-memory-usage-for-a-group-of-processes)